# Removing block of script before the web page renders

Tags: javascript, facebook

We want a method to quickly determine a certain condition so we can remove block of javascript such as the adsense control before the page renders.  The condition we want to determine is that the current user is viewing the contents of an asp.net website from within Facebook's Platform as an IFrame App.  Is it possible to use some like this

IsFacebookHere function(){

```
 FB.init({ 
        appId: 'my appID value', 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true, 
        status: true });

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
           //  Remove the Adsense from the User experience
        } else {
            // do something else...maybe show a login prompt
        }
    });
```

}

Iso, where to place it such that it is most effective? I'm thinking that document.ready is too late.  Any alternate approach or suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> We want a method to quickly determine a certain condition so we can remove block of javascript such as the adsense control before the page renders. The condition we want to determine is that the current user is viewing the contents of an asp.net website from within Facebook's Platform as an IFrame App.

You should do that server-side already: Look for a `signed_request` parameter – if that is passed to your script, then it’s most likely called within the Facebook iframe.